# Can an arduino display pixel art I make on my phone?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I'm planning on trying to make an app or use something like Blynk with a [Seeeduino Board](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Seeed-XIAO-BLE-nRF52840-p-5201.html) that supports Bluetooth to see if I can make the board display something I draw or type on my phone. Example would be like I type "Hello World" and it displays hello world on a connected display or I like draw a triangle on my phone screen and use some cheap display to show the triangle on the arduino. Ideally this would all work independently when paired via bluetooth. Id also later like to add the ability of the app to send stuff to another phone (via email or something) and then display that on their device. Any help or links to a items I would need would be great (assuming this is possible over arduino and I dont need to just use a raspberry pi).

Comment: why not? ... there are many variations of Arduino hardware

Comment: this site is not a forum ... it is a question and answer site for answering focused questions ... please add a clear, answerable question to your post

Comment: please do not misuse tags ... there is nothing about mechanical engineering in your post